# Select record that has specific records related, but no additional records related

Tags: sql, sqlite

For a many to many relationship, for example Classes and Students, I'd like to select all `Classes` with exactly a given membership.

```
Students         Classes        StudentClass
=========       ============    =================
id              id              student     class
--              ---             --------   -------
1               1               1           1
2               2               2           1
3                               3           1
4                               1           2
5                               2           2             
                                3           2
                                4           2
```

With example data, If I give the query S1, S2, S3 - it should return Class 1 only, and exclude Class 4 because it contains an additional student.

Comment: I would use a `LATERAL` select but I don't know if SQLite has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select class
from studentclass
group by class
having count(case when student in (1,2,3) then 1 end) = 3
   and count(*) = 3
```

- [Online Demo](http://rextester.com/PIZ4892)

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir well that would be a very poor database design to allow a student to sign up for the same class.  easy to fix with `distinct` though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/00225/1

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir also you should try your query with that same duplicated data -- you're missing 1 more `distinct` as well...

Answer (score 1):

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/832b0/12)

You can do it like below :

```
select class from StudentClass
where class in(
    select class from StudentClass where student in(1,2,3) 
    group by class having count(distinct student)=3
) group by class
having count(distinct student)=3
```

Comment: This only works with the sample data... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d259f/1